# How do I expose a combo box on a user control for databinding?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, attributes

I'm creating a composite user control and trying to exposing the controls as properties so that I can databind them from the form that I drop the user control onto.  One of the controls I'm trying to expose is a combobox and I can't seem to figure out how to expose this combobox to the designer.  I'm trying the following code that I've cobbled together from what bits of documentation I can find but so far no joy.

```
<Category("Data"), Bindable(True), _
Browsable(True), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), _
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible), _
AttributeProvider(GetType(IListSource))> _
Public Property RollbackCombo As ComboBox
    Get
        Return cboRollBack
    End Get
    Set(value As ComboBox)
        cboRollBack = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Just to elaborate a bit, I'm using property declarations like this one to bind to the text boxes on the composite control and I'm trying to achieve something like it for a combobox, the datasource of it at least.

```
<Category("Appearance"),
Bindable(True),
Browsable(True),
EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)> _
Public Property Title As String
    Get
        Return TitleTextbox.Text
    End Get

    Set(value As String)
        TitleTextbox.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, but the property editor probably doesn't know what to do with a property of type ComboBox.

Have you tried exposing the DataSource property of the ComboBox instead?

```
<Category("Data"), Bindable(True), _
Browsable(True), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), _
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible), _
AttributeProvider(GetType(IListSource))> _
Public Property RollbackComboDataSource As Object
    Get
        Return cboRollBack.DataSource
    End Get
    Set(value As Object)
        cboRollBack.DataSource = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks Cory, I'll give that a shot - I think that's on the right lines.

Comment: That got it :)  Nice one Cory - you're a legend!  I had to set the displayname and valuename fields to pick the right columns from the data source but that was trivial to do in the user control itself.

Comment: i've been searching for this answer for a week now.. and i've stumbled upon tens of questions.. each were specifying the browsable option, or the ilistsource attribute or bindable property... i just tried your code now, and it works.. it seems we need them all..